# Angular JS replace values ng grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am newbie in angular JS and I think that I need help.

This is my issue : 
I have a ng-grid which is linked with a table. Within there are values and a ID (which is a foreignkey from a another table). I don't want to show the ID but another field in this foreign table.

```
CompanyFactory.getCompanies().success(function (data) { $scope.objs = data })

  $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'objs',
        showGroupPanel: true,
        jqueryUIDraggable: true,
        columnDefs: [
              { field: 'COMP_NAME', displayName: 'comp_name'},
              { field: 'COUNTRY', displayName: 'country' },
              { field: 'LU_SECTOR_ID', displayName: 'sector', },
            ]

    };
```

I want show the sector_name field instead of the sector_ID field. How can I make the relation between  these two tables ?

```
 $scope.countries = [
            { COMP_NAME: 'KOLI', COUNTRY: 'KOLI_COUNTRY', LU_SECTOR_ID: '1'},
            { COMP_NAME: 'ZOLI', COUNTRY: 'ZOLI_COUNTRY', LU_SECTOR_ID: '2'},
            { COMP_NAME: 'TULI', COUNTRY: 'TULI_COUNTRY', LU_SECTOR_ID: '3'},

        ];

 $scope.sector= [
            { LU_SECTOR_ID: '1', LU_SECTOR_NAME: 'SECTOR_1'},
            { LU_SECTOR_ID: '2', LU_SECTOR_NAME: 'SECTOR_2'},
            { LU_SECTOR_ID: '3', LU_SECTOR_NAME: 'SECTOR_3'},

        ];
```

I would like to show in the ng-grid the SECTOR NAME instead of the SECTOR_ID.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of a the `data` object? If you need to literally join the objects before binding, you will need to do it manually.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I meant the `$scope.objs = data`, could you post a JSON snippet of the object? Not the columns.

Comment: How can you make the binding manually ? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: See my answer, you should link both objects before binding into the grid. It will be simpler and way more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to answer the question without the information of the `data` object.

However, suppose that your `data` object returned by your `CompanyFactory` is something like:

```
[
    {
       "COMP_NAME": "Tomms",
       "COUNTRY": "France",
       "LU_SECTOR_ID": "9":,

       "SECTOR": { "SECTOR_NAME": "IT" }
    }
]
```

You just need to bind the correct field:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'objs',
    showGroupPanel: true,
    jqueryUIDraggable: true,
    columnDefs: [
          { field: 'COMP_NAME', displayName: 'comp_name'},
          { field: 'COUNTRY', displayName: 'country' },

          // Here
          { field: 'SECTOR.SECTOR_NAME', displayName: 'sector', },
        ]

};
```

But, if you returning both objects separated you will need to link it manually. My suggestion is to perform that in the server side and return the object like I used as an example.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here

```
{ field: 'LU_SECTOR_ID', displayName: 'sector', }
```

Specifically

```
LU_SECTOR_ID
```

you need to change the name of this variable to be the name on the objs and not the id